# Unix time as int to local time

Tags: c++, time, localtime, ctime

I have a function which returns a timestamp in unix time as int.

I need to convert this int to a string `dd/mm/yy` in local time. The "local" part is causing me problems, if it weren't for that, I could have just made my own function to convert it.

I have searched around , and it seems the `ctime` class from the standard library would be ideal for this, in a manner like this:

```
int unixtime;

std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(unixtime));
```

Sadly, only `*time_t` is accepted. Is there any way I can convert int into this format, or any better way to get local time from unix time as int?

Answer (score 2):

`time_t` is by definition an arithmetic type, you can just do:

```
time_t ts = unixtime;
std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&ts));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/* localtime example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts, printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

  return 0;
}'
```

You can simply use type time_t it will give you the time.

Answer (score 0):

"The ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() functions all take an argument of data type time_t which represents calendar time. When interpreted as an absolute time value, it represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)."

**sources**:

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime
- http://linux.die.net/man/7/time

Answer (score 0):

To print current time in dd/mm/yy, you may try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    char date_buff[40];
    time_t time_value = time(0);
    struct tm* my_tm = localtime(&time_value);
    strftime(date_buff, sizeof(date_buff), "%d/%m/%y\n", my_tm);
    std::cout << date_buff << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `time_t` is not guaranteed by the C specification.

Unix and POSIX-compliant systems implement the `time_t` type as a signed integer (typically 32 or 64 bits wide) which represents the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch. So you may just do the following

```
std::time_t my_time = static_cast<std::time_t>(unixtime);
```

However, it is better to not to assume time to be an `int` and replace your time function with the appropriate time handling and return `std::time_t` or `struct tm`